# Can i compare two Images?

Tags: objective-c

I want to compare two images each other. If that possible then give me code. I was tried that but that was a take more memory and also take huge time to compare.

Here in my device two same image available but that's url are different.So first i was convert that url to image and after that  convert into data  and compare each other.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
             [library assetForURL:imageUrl
                      resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                        UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];

                          NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.01);
                          NSData *data2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.01);

                            if ([data1 isEqualToData:data2]){
                                NSLog(@"YES");
                            }
                            else{
                                NSLog(@"NO");
                            }

                      }

                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                         NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!");
                     } ];
```

Comment: your question lacks any research or attempts where you tried to solve this yourself accept compare between bites. You adding give me codes will get your question downvoted, since this is frowned up. You might just want to clarify how you want you image compared.

Comment: I want to compare fast without using more memory. Here this code take more time and memory.

Comment: Here in my device two same image available but that's url are different.So first i was convert that url to image and after that  convert into data  and compare each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare both images using their NSData..

```
- (BOOL)image:(UIImage *)image1 isEqualTo:(UIImage *)image2
{
    NSData *imgData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    NSData *imgData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);

    return [imgData1 isEqual:imgData2];
}
```